# apply Ito's Lemma to X/(X+Y)

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I have a question of applying Ito's Lemma in the following problem,

Assume both X and Y follow the Geometric Brownian Motion, how to use Ito's Lemma to get the process of X/(X+Y)?

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thank you for this information.

Comment: You need to apply the Ito's Lemma to the function $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{x+y}$ along with the process $X_t$ and $Y_t$. I suppose that you know the dynamics of $X_t$ and $Y_t$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have figured it out now. As you pointed out, I should take it as a multivariate function. Best